# Google Script - New Date() where do i put this? & Return ContentService

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code and I want to add a date and time stamp when the data is uploaded. I have set the variable and tried a few combinations to get this **to post at sh.AppendRow**.  Some have error'd the post and others are blank. Any help to show where I need to add this to the code would be great. I am trying to achieve a date and time stamp when each record is Appended.

```
function doPost(e) {
var data = eval(e.postData.contents) ;
var usr = data[0][0];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(usr) ;
var now = new Date()// Variable for date


if ( sh == null ) { 
    ss.insertSheet(usr);
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(usr) ;
    var pos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(usr);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(pos);
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    ss.moveActiveSheet(sheets.length);
    sh.appendRow(["User","Asset ID","Project"]);
    }

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
sh.appendRow(data[i]);
}

return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Collected Saved") ;
}
```

Thank you.

My second question is could the a **count** of the appended rows be inserted in the below script instead of a "Data Collected Saved".  Perhaps eg. **"12 rows appended"**

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Collected Saved") ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the timestamp in column D:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i]; // variable to hold the values to be appended
    rowData.push(now);     // add timestamp to the end of the row of items
    sh.appendRow(rowData); // append to sheet
  }
```

---

If you want to put the timestamp in column A, you could use [unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

```
rowData.unshift(now); // add timestamp to the beginning of the row of items
```

---

Don't forget to change the header row accordingly.

---

To send back the number of rows appended you could try:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(data.length + " rows appended") ;
```

Comment: Thank you ADW, much appreciated this has worked perfectly..  May ask another question?

Comment: return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Collected Saved") ;
}

Is there a way to insert a count of rows appended?

Comment: What is the question? Usually, it is best to post a new question so others may benefit. But if it is related, you could edit your question.